# Прикрепление нескольких файлов в форме

Tags: php

Есть код прикрепления файла в форме.

```
<?php
  $to = "test@gmail.com";
  $from = "admin@tite.com";
  $subject = "Заполнена контактная форма на сайте ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $message = "Имя пользователя: ".$_POST['nameFF']."\nEmail пользователя ".$_POST['contactFF']."\nТелефон пользователя ".$_POST['telFF']."\nСообщение: ".$_POST['projectFF']."\n\nАдрес сайта: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

  $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));
  $filesize = '';
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
  $message="
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"

--$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message";
     if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'])) {
         $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'])));
         $filename = $_FILES['fileFF']['name'];
         $filetype = $_FILES['fileFF']['type'];
         $filesize = $_FILES['fileFF']['size'];
         $message.="

--$boundary

Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$filename\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"

$attachment";
     }

   $message.="
--$boundary--";



  if ($filesize < 10000000) { // проверка на общий размер всех файлов. Многие почтовые сервисы не принимают вложения больше 10 МБ
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo $_POST['nameFF'].', Ваше сообщение отправлено, спасибо!';
  } else {
    echo 'Извините, письмо не отправлено. Размер всех файлов превышает 10 МБ.';
  }
?>
```

Как сделать, чтобы можно было прикрепить несколько файлов? Помогите пожалуйстааа

Comment: Использовать библиотеку, в которой это делается легко и просто. И код выглядеть красиво будет

Comment: @ArchDemon немного подробнее расскажите пожалуйста. Или может знаете где пример посмотреть?

Comment: https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mail/message/attachments/ - хардкорная библиотека. https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html - лайтовая библиотека. Я пользовался обеими

Comment: @ArchDemon что-то не получается. Не могли бы вы пожалуйста, немного подсказать? Буду очень признательным)

Comment: Не зная что не получается, я не могу вам ничего посоветовать.

Comment: @ ArchDemon если можете, напишите пожалуйста что нужно конкретно в этом коде изменить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому-то интересно, нашел решение

```
<?php
  $to = "mail@gmail.com";
  $from = "admin@site.com";
  $subject = "Заполнена контактная форма на сайте ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $message = "Имя пользователя: ".$_POST['nameFF']."\nEmail пользователя ".$_POST['contactFF']."\nТелефон пользователя ".$_POST['telFF']."\nСообщение: ".$_POST['projectFF']."\n\nАдрес сайта: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

  $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));
  $filesize = '';
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
  $message="
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"

--$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message";
  for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['fileFF']['name']);$i++) {
     if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
         $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])));
         $filename = $_FILES['fileFF']['name'][$i];
         $filetype = $_FILES['fileFF']['type'][$i];
         $filesize += $_FILES['fileFF']['size'][$i];
         $message.="

--$boundary
Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$filename\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"

$attachment";
     }
   }

   $message.="
--$boundary--";



  if ($filesize < 10000000) { // проверка на общий размер всех файлов. Многие почтовые сервисы не принимают вложения больше 10 МБ
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo $_POST['nameFF'].', Ваше сообщение отправлено, спасибо!';
  } else {
    echo 'Извините, письмо не отправлено. Размер всех файлов превышает 10 МБ.';
  }
?>
```